# How do I calculate the average of top 20 percent of a collection in MongoDB Aggregate?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mongomapper

In a collection like: `books : [{ stars: 10, valid: true }, { stars: 24, valid: false }, { stars: 76, valid: true }, ...]`, is simple calculate average with:

```
db.books.aggregate([
    { $match : {
        valid: true
    }},

    { $group : {
        _id: null,
        avg: { $avg: "$stars" } // <- How calculate $avg of top 20%?
    }}
])
```

But, if I want average of top 20 percent of stars instead of average of all stars?

**PS:** Without know collection(valid: true) size, because unlike my example, I perform a lot of `$unwind`

**OBS:**

```
> db.version()
2.4.10
```

Comment: Top 20% means? Top 20% of the stars based on their `star` property value or the top 20% records in the collection whose `valid` property is true?

Answer (score 1):

You need to fire two queries to achieve this.

Get the total count of stars whose `valid` attribute is `true`.

```
var bookCount = db.books.count({"valid":true});
```

Calculate the number of records top 20% for which the average needs to be calculated.

```
var limit = Math.ceil(.2*bookCount);
```

Perform the aggregation operation:

- `Match` only those records, whose `valid` attribute is `true`.
- `Sort` the records based on the `stars` attribute value, in descending
  order, so that the top stars come first.
- `Limit` the top 20% of the records.
- `Group` them and calculate their averages.

The Code:

```
db.books.aggregate([
{$match:{"valid":true}},
{$sort:{"stars":-1}},
{$limit:limit},
{$group:{"_id":null,"avg":{$avg:"$stars"}}}
])
```

> *I perform a lot of $unwind*

Your Sample data nor your code reflect this.